# A short day at the mall

Tags: riddle, story, knowledge

Today I was going around the mall(in various stores) and I was recording what random customers had in their cart.  After my research I also had two questions. Here are some of the items the customers had in their cart.

**Cart 1**
Tissues, benadryl, and a neti pot.

**Cart 2**
Latex gloves, wide popsicle sticks, and hand sanitizer

**Cart 3**
A tiny mask, milk, a small desk fan, and a turkey.

**Cart 4**
A stress ball, a book titled “How to Speak in Public”, and another called “How to be extraverted”.

**Cart 5**
A “for Dummies” book, and a deck of cards(but I noticed the package was broken and they were spilling all over the ground)

**Cart 6**
An “I don’t care” mug, an Edgar Allen poe compilation book, and a shirt that says “don’t talk to me”.

> 1.Who are these people
>
> 2.What could be in cart #7?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your shoppers happen to be:

> The Seven Dwarfs

Cart 1:

> **Sneezy** — items which help prevent or deal with sneezing or its causes

Cart 2:

> **Doc** — items attributed to medical doctors

Cart 3:

> **Sleepy** — items which induce sleep

Cart 4:

> **Bashful** — items to counteract shyness in public

Cart 5:

> **Dopey** — The items reflect his dull intellect or ineptitude. (From @Chowzen: Dopey is “not playing with a full deck”)

Cart 6:

> **Grumpy** — items which reflect his abrasive personality

That leaves:

> **Happy**

whose cart may contain items such as:

> Chocolates, games, flowers, and perhaps a puppy!

Title:

> A **short** day: refers to a dwarf’s infamously short stature

Comment: That is the correct answer! I like your description of each, especially happy's :D